# Any idea why i am getting this error for react-native when run for android

Tags: firebase, react-native

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
86 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 84 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-firebase_app:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/nikhilsharma/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/nikhilsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3ba7065493e6116f45b5a3b27f241b3e/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/nikhilsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3ba7065493e6116f45b5a3b27f241b3e/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

JDK 11
Gradle 8.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Reference to this link might be beneficial for resolving the issue.

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1194